# Mongoose sort using a model variable and a forEach loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have the following model:

```
var lectureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    url: String,
    description: String,
    order: Number,
    free: Boolean,
    lectResOne: String,
    lectResTwo: String,
    lectResThree: String,
    lectResFour: String,
    extLinkOne: String,
    extLinkTwo: String,
    extLinkThree: String,
    extLinkFour: String
});
```

I want to sort this model using the 'order' variable value using something similar on my show.ejs page:

```
<% lectures.sort().forEach(function(lecture){ %>
    <% if(lecture.free == false) { %>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="abc">
                    <p class="centered-text"> <%=lecture.name%> </p>
                        <img src="<%= lecture.image %>">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="/lectures/<%= lecture._id %>">Begin</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

I'm using mongoose version:

```
"mongoose": "^4.11.12"
```

So for example, I will have the following Lectures:

Lecture abc with an order value of 5

Lecture def with an order value of 7

Lecture ghi with an order value of 2

I want these to be displayed in the following order from the forEach loop output:

2, 5, 7

Thanks

Comment: You can ask mongoose to sort it for you using `sort` method for example `Lectures.find().sort({ order: 1 })` docs here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Thanks, I have tried something similar but I'm afraid is doesn't work. I've amended by code to: '<% lectures.find().sort({ order: 1 }).forEach(function(lecture){ %>' but get the following error returned: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: By `Lectures` a meant Your mongoose model not the actual result of querying the db. `var Lectures = mongoose.model('Lectures', lecturesSchema); Lectures.find( somequery ).sort({ order: 1 })` and your ejs will be `<% lectures.forEach(function(lecture){ %`

Comment: Got ya. Yep, now working. Thanks a lot Molda! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Molda:

Model amended to:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var lectureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    url: String,
    description: String,
    order: Number,
    free: Boolean,
    lectResOne: String,
    lectResTwo: String,
    lectResThree: String,
    lectResFour: String,
    extLinkOne: String,
    extLinkTwo: String,
    extLinkThree: String,
    extLinkFour: String
});

// Code added to acheive lecture sorting on lectures and mlectures page.
var Lecture = mongoose.model('Lecture', lectureSchema);
Lecture.find().sort({ order: 1 });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Lecture", lectureSchema);
```

.ejs page amended to:

```
    <% lectures.forEach(function(lecture){ %>
        <% if(lecture.free == false) { %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="abc">
                        <p class="centered-text"> <%=lecture.name%> </p>
                            <img src="<%= lecture.image %>">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="/lectures/<%= lecture._id %>">Begin</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    <% }); %>
```